# Testing onEnter in react-redux-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-redux

I've got an onEnter defined in my routes container and I'm trying to figure out how to write some tests for this;

```
export default class Root extends React.Component<IRootProps, void> {
    store: Redux.Store<IAppState> = configureStore();
    history: ReactRouterReduxHistory = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, this.store);

    checkAuth = (nextState: RouterState, replace: RedirectFunction): void => {
        console.log(this.store.getState().authToken);
        if (nextState.location.pathname !== '/login') {
            if (this.store.getState().authToken) {
                if (nextState.location.state && nextState.location.pathname) {
                    replace(nextState.location.pathname);
                }
            } else {
                replace('/login');
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <div>
                    <Router history={this.history}>
                        <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                        <Route onEnter={this.checkAuth} path='/' component={App}>
                            <IndexRoute component={Counter}/>
                        </Route>
                    </Router>
                    <DevTools />
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Writing a test to mount the component was easy enough;

```
function setup() {
    const middlewares: any[] = [];
    const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
    const initialState = {};
    const store:any = mockStore(initialState);

    const component = mount(<Root store={store as Store<IAppState>} />);

    return {
        component: component,
        history: history
    };
}

describe('Root component', () => {
    it('should create the root component', () => {
        const {component, history} = setup();
        expect(component.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

But I'm at a loss for how to actually test that `checkAuth` is invoked and actually performs the `replace` call correctly (and renders the right thing).

I'm sure this is trivial but google fails me so far.. Any examples/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file with your onEnter callback and test it there. I am calling such files `guards`. Your root guard will look for example like this:

```js
export default (store: Redux.Store<IAppState>) => (nextState: RouterState, replace: RedirectFunction): void => {
    if (nextState.location.pathname !== '/login') {
        if (store.getState().authToken) {
            if (nextState.location.state && nextState.location.pathname) {
                replace(nextState.location.pathname);
            }
        } else {
            replace('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

and the route:

```js
<Route onEnter={rootGuard(this.store)} path='/' component={App}>
```